# Prizes/Swag for our anniversary competion?

Tags: discussion

As you will see from the [associated question on what competition we should have to celebrate our anniversary](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/485), we will also need to think about prizes.

The message from SEI is to think up the sort of things we would like - don't worry about cost at this stage. Once they have a better idea as to the scope of prizes they can then choose what may fit.

Obvious simple prizes are the usual:

- T-Shirts
- Pens
- the exceptionally cool Security branded torches (so desirable, [@Jin needs to steal one next time he visits SEI HQ in NYC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4947435#4947435))

or if we have a clean-up type of competition:

- badges such as Necromancer or Revival

but what else would you like to see?

Write your thoughts as individual answers so we can vote on them.

Answer (score 7):

I still like the idea of Sec SE branded lockpicks a la Kevin Mitnick's set:

[image]

@Iszi priced these:

> If we wanted just one each, it seems the cost would be at least $280
>   for the first two pages of users.  That's $100 for a one-time film
>   creation fee.  Then $1.80 per card, up to 500, minimum of 100.  After
>   500 cards, the cost drops to $1.60 per. 
>   http://www.metalcards.com/metalcards/mcpricing.html

Comment: Unfortunately, these things are borderline illegal in a lot of places.  I think it depends on how functional an law enforcement officer believes they are.  I had one of these and stopped carrying it in my wallet to prevent any possible issues.

Comment: Lockpicks used to be here in the UK, but then law enforcement realised that criminals use bricks to gain enry. The only people using lockpicks are security professionals, hobbyists and spies.

Answer (score 5):

A rucksack in the deep blue with the embroidered logo would be very nice - and good advertising, but it would need to be a good bag. Many security geeks love a decent quality laptop/swag/kit bag.

Could range from under £5 each with [this](http://www.micromarketingltd.com/drawstring-and-rucksack/le7333-ripstop-lightweight-triangle-bag.php)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Prize ideas:

- licence for Burp Suite ($290)
- licence for Metasploit Pro ($5000)
- Wifi Pineapple ($90)
- Teensy boards ($16)
- Wireshark book ($100)

Comment: Problem with this list is that needness in these items depends on specialization. Although they are good for those who needs them

Comment: All prizes depend on specialization. From bags, to shirts, to tools. 'Needness' need not be required: the prize can be worth more than the utility.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to see a Sec.SE *polo* shirt at some point.  This would be a good excuse to make one.

under $20

Answer (score 2):

- Books about open source projects (e.g nmap book at $50)
- Traditional promo items (e.g. shirts and stickers)
- Electronic devices (e.g. products from [Pwnie Express](http://pwnieexpress.com/) products which start at $595)
- Hacking kits! However you want to interpret that.

I would argue **against software licenses** unless they are support contracts for open source projects. StackExchange is driven by cooperation and the free exchange of ideas, let's keep with that spirit.

Comment: trying to work out prices - being a bit challenged with some of these :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how nobody mentioned this before, but a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) would be a great prize.

I know a lot of people have already got them, but they rock and there's no harm in owning more than one!

Comment: How it can be used? I mean why it will be a good prize?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Their uses are innumerable. It's a good prize because they're popular among techie crowds, they're interesting, and they have uses in security (e.g. hiding one in a network rack and sniffing traffic).

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Rewards:**

- I was wondering if Security Stack Exchange as a reward could tie up with
  other known certification companies like EC Council or Offensive
  Security to collaboratively give a discount or sponsorship on
  security related recognized certifications to the winners.
- DefCon style badges couriered to the winners. I mean who doesn't
  like DefCon badges?
- An official letter from Security Stack Exchange stating the users
  cooperation in building up the website. Maybe the top users could get
  it for free while others need to pay for postage?
- The winners of the competition get their names bronzed immortally on
  a static page in Security Stack Exchange or so.

Comment: The top users on each Stack Exchange site already get goodies from Stack Exchange, so I'm not sure adding these as competition prizes is that useful. What were you thinking rigarding badges? We have had a couple of mentions of things like lapel pins etc.

Comment: The DefCon badges are awesome.  For anyone unaware, the badges usually have micro controllers on them: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2009/08/hacking-the-defcon-17-badges/

Answer (score 0):

@schroeder's suggestion of Metasploit and Wi-Fi Pineapple gave me an idea:

Wi-Spy spectrum analyzer and Chanalyzer license.  $200-$1000, depending on Wi-Spy model and Chanalyzer version.

http://www.metageek.net/products/wi-spy/