# Is deliberately trying to find bugs allowed?

Tags: discussion

Out of interest, If I purposely try and find bugs/vulnerabilities in the site, is that permitted/encouraged/discouraged?
I haven't found any, but occasionally I run out of things to do so a live system would be interesting to poke at. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean Stack Exchange, then no - it would be illegal in many countries, and you could expect all manner of problems if you tried it.

From [this earlier query](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/814/485) by @AviD on the topic, we got the official SE response:

> Sorry, we've discussed this internally and it's not something we
>   (Stack Exchange) can sanction. In addition to the legal ramifications,
>   we're not comfortable with encouraging attacks on systems with
>   people's private information.

Comment: Alright, that's fine. what happens if i come across some kind of vulnerability/bug? Does that get posted up in here then?

Comment: @D3C4FF I wouldn't post it on Meta - email it to SE. Again, these servers have personal info on them - don't post a way to get to it on Meta!