# Can I ask about lock-picking and locksport?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/are-questions-about-lock-security-on-topic) question suggests that questions about physical lock security are on-topic, and since lock-picking and locksport are huge topics concerning lock security, I think they should be on-topic. While physical security questions aren't nearly as common as IT ones, lock security is still an integral part of security.

Are questions about lock-picking and locksport on-topic?

Comment: Possibly related to https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/are-questions-about-lock-security-on-topic

Comment: That question was already mentioned in my question...

Comment: I just saw. I would like to change my comment to "Certainly related to"

Answer (score 1):

It would be borderline, as long as the question is about the *physical security of information*.

The more important issue is if anyone in the community can actually answer the question. Historically, physical security questions do not get a lot of engagement.

Comment: A Chicken and Egg problem. No questions about locks are asked, no experts are attracted. A lack of experts causes people not to ask questions.

Comment: @MechMK1 yep - not a criteria for not asking the question, just a reality to consider when choosing *here* to ask the question.